# How to verify if L1 license key and which one is installed for oemcrypto

Tags: python, widevine

I am new in this widevine/oemcrypto world and I want a way to verify if L1 license is installed for oemcrypto and which license with which device ID or so.

I have the below keybox.xml with two license for different device IDs and I am able to install one by one but can't really verify which one is now active?

The keybox.xml is processed via a python script that creates a keybox.bin according to which device ID I have selected as argument.

The created keybox.bin I can then install it on a android device which seems valid and installed successful.

I can do the same with the second one and it is also installed successful.
But which one is now valid and how can I see which is now active?

Thanks